# Plaid or Flinks, Which is a better open-banking data API in Canada(and the US in future)?

Tags: api

I am integrating financial API to my mortgage scoring model, and I have found two data APIs, Flinks and Plaid. They all seem with the same price and function, and I wonder what is their differences and which one is better and serves better to fintech developers? And also please share your thoughts on what makes a good financial data API.

Comment: A little late to the party, but curious what you learnt and what you are currently using. Thanks @user598604